# how to choose or write my own java data structure allowing multi attributes search

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a pretty large list containing many instances of one class, this class has many attributes(member variables). My problem is to find a feasible data structure to store these instances that allow searches based on multiple attributes like database search(i.e. A Student class, each student has age, date of birth, grade and GPA.find all 2nd year students whose ages are between 20 and 23). The Map seems not applicable as it only allow single key and if I create multi attribute index for searching, the big O is still not decreased. I also considered using trees like AVL tree, and I don't think it would work.

I'd be grateful if someone could give me some hints.

Comment: One option would be to actually use a database. Maybe an in memory one. Or maybe a search engine (Lucene, Solr, ElasticSearch)

Comment: can you be more clear about the data items in your requirements ?

Comment: @JensSchauder I really do think I need a database, but as it is a data structure question, I'm only allowed to solve this problem within memory using a data structure.

Comment: @SujalMandal Hi, I've updated the question, hope you can understand it now.

Comment: @JensSchauder:  That'd make the data structure a B-tree (or one of its variants).

Comment: @simons What is the efficiency you are looking at? Is O(n) good enough?

Comment: @user3437460 I think it's not good enough because I can just use a single list to achieve O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an [Inverted Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) (using attribute name + value as keys) or possibly one Inverted Index per attribute. A search would build the intersection of all results found for each attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

- Build an AVL tree with objects sorted by the most recurrent attribute (just one, e.g. "id" or "name").
- Then create a search function that instead of taking a value, takes a Java lambda expression F (so your seacrh condition must be something like `F(myObj) == true` instead of `myObj.deFaultAttribute == searchParameter`)
- For the example you gave, F could be something like `((myObj) -> myObj.year==2 && myObj.age>=20 && myObj.age<=23)`

I hope it helps.

Comment: I believe this would work but I'm still confused whether it really could improve the time complexity or not, I think there is no difference between this solution and using directly a List for searching(except searches based on the key).